# ViewController does not conform to protocol AnyObject error with UISwipeGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, swift

I get this error when trying to implement the swipe gesture:

```
var swipeGesture = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: slideToRightWithGestureRecognizer)

func slideToRightWithGestureRecognizer() {

}
```

My ViewController looks like this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

}
```

I get the error on `target: self`, do I have to implement some delegates or what else is the problem ?

Comment: Add a parameter to your `slideToRightWithGestureRecognizer` of type `UISwipeGestureRecognizer`. E.g. `func slideToRightWithGestureRecognizer(sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {`

Comment: I also tried that, but with no effect

Comment: What's your error message?

Comment: ViewController -> () -> ViewController!' does not conform to protocol 'AnyObject'

Comment: You need to put quotation marks around `slideToRightWithGestureRecognizer`. Other than that, no idea...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume that `swipeGesture` is a property - in that case, the problem is that you are referencing `self` during property initialization, which is not allowed, because `self` is not available until all properties have been initialized.

I think the best way to fix that is by initializing the property in the `viewDidLoad` method, but of course the property has to be an optional - I think it's safe to use an implicitly unwrapped one in this case:

```
var swipeGesture: UISwipeGestureRecognizer!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.swipeGesture = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "slideToRightWithGestureRecognizer")
}
```

Comment: Side note: this is a typical example of a nonsense compilation error message. There are quite a few like that...